# Trying to determine whether a sound deficiency is due to hardware

Tags: windows-7, audio

Stack Overflow said it is OK to ask windows questions here.

I am using the headphone jack to listen to music.  Recently, I have been able to hear only one side.  I tried doing several things which did not help:

1. The first thing to try is to use a different headphone as the problem might be with the headphone.  However, the different headphones exhibit the same problem.
2. The next thing was to go through the sound settings.  I looked through everything I could find and everything said it was working correctly.  Levels were set, etc.
3. I tried the Microsoft diagnostics but could not get a solution.

I got to the setup (see the picture) and clicked on each of the little speaker icons (see picture).  The one circled in green gave a sound.  The one in red did not.

Does this mean it is a hardware problem (something shot) or is there something else to try?[image]

Comment: The strange thing, as I was listening just now, for maybe 1 second I heard sound in both left and right.  Then it went back to just the left side.

Comment: Oh, and yes I did try tebooting.

Comment: Does your machine have both rear and forward headphone jacks? Which ones are you using?

Comment: The ones in front.

Comment: I don't see any rear ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your computer is a desktop computer, it likely has two sets of audio jacks; one pair on the motherboard or on the sound card, and another pair on the front of the case.  If you have a laptop, it is likely you have only one pair of analog connections.

If you have a desktop, please try to locate the rear-facing jacks if you have been using the front-facing ones.  Case plate jacks go out more quickly than the ones built into the motherboard or sound card, as they are usually a bit more fragile and less well-mounted. Many have the front jacks glued into place, instead of screwed to something or soldered; this means that repeatedly removing and reconnecting jacks to the sockets can cause the socket to become loose in the casing, which gives you the symptoms you are having now..

If you are using a laptop, that's basically the same deal as with the face plate on a PC.

In both cases, you can use a USB headset to bypass the problem.

Comment: I will check.  I do have a USB headset but it has only 1 ear side.  The other is just a thinkg to clamp to your head to keep it on, and it has a microphone.

Comment: yes there is a green jack, but it exhibits the same problem

Comment: If you have tried both sets of jacks and get the same issue from both, and the issue also occurs with a headset that doesn't exhibit the same problem when plugged into other devices (make sure you test that, too) then the sound device for your computer may be going out.  Also, make sure you're using the latest drivers for your sound card; this may be a bug that was resolved in the software.

Comment: OK I will check the driver.  I unfortunately do not have authorization to update it if it is not the latest ;-(

Comment: So why is this the accepted answer?

Comment: Because I get yelled at if I don't select one ;-)

Comment: OK as I said I tried more than one headphone and had the same problem.  The weird thing is, I tried the headphones in my phone too and also heard only out of one side.  Which means, either my phone and PC are broken in one channel, or both sets of headphones are.  Or both ;-)

Comment: If they're those little dangly ear buds, it's very likely both sets of headphones are.   Those things break wires if you sneeze at them funny, unless it's a *really* nice (i.e. $30+) set, and even then, they're fragile.